# Echoing a count returns the word Array instead of the number

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with the query below. It echoes the word Array instead of a number.

Am I not using the `mysql_fetch_assoc` correctly? The query works in `phpmyadmin`, without the variables of course.

The variables do echo the right data when tested. Can anyone help me to correct this?

```
$uniquejuror = "SELECT COUNT(case_number) AS total2 
FROM CaseJuryPool 
WHERE CaseJuryPool.case_juror = '{$uid}'; 
AND CaseJuryPool.case_number = '{$casenumber}'"; 

$uj = mysql_query($uniquejuror); 
$rowuj = mysql_fetch_assoc($uj); 
echo $rowuj['total2'];
```

Comment: var_dump($rowuj); and you'll understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), results need to be looped thru the result, you could do:

```
$rowuj = mysql_fetch_row($uj); 
echo $rowuj[0];
```

BTW, This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: If he only wants one row( the count total ) he doesn't need a loop

Comment: @Ander2 i didnt say he needs a loop, i said with mysql_fetch_assoc() results need to be looped..!